# How to add collectionview as subview to viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

i had a little problem with my collectionview when i want to add it as a subview to my ProfileViewController. The problem occurred when i want to reload the collectionview and xcode give me an error **property 'collectionview' not found on object of type ProfileViewController**. 
how can i overcome this problem? do i to create a new collectionview class file and set it to collectionview on ProfileViewController ? Below is the image for my storyboard.

the image for storyboard is at this link. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSE29.png . 
I can't attached an image to this post cause my reputation is low.

Comment: So does the view load initially and only give the error when you attempt to reload the collection view? Or does the crash occur immediately when loading the view containing the collection view. The error you're getting is usually caused by an outlet set on an object that no longer exists (outlet was connected in IB then deleted in the code).

Comment: you have to connect the view in the storyboard to an IBOutlet in your code. Xcode won't do that for you, Xcode only does this when you add a CollectionViewController to your storyboard. If you call that IBOutlet `collectionView` your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want make sure your ProfileViewController conforms to the UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate protocols and when you create the collection view inside the ProfileViewController make sure you do:

```
collectionView.delegate = self;
collectionView.dataSource = self;
```

Sounds like you're trying to use self.collectionView, where that property doesn't exist on the ProfileViewController.

Comment: I already put <UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate> on my ProfileViewController. And i also tried to put collectionView.delegate = self; and collectionView.dataSource = self; in my ProfileViewController but my xcode give me an error. below is the image for .h and .m file.

.h file http://i.imgur.com/RWvQhLT.png
.m file http://i.imgur.com/T2jgkDm.png

Comment: Where do you create the collection view? You can't reference self.collectionView if you don't add a collectionView property on the view controller.

Comment: what do u mean by creating collectionview? i just drag out collectionview and put it in my ProfileViewController by using storyboard. Here is my .h and .m code

.h file http://pastebin.com/yNMVpBV9
.m file http://pastebin.com/YG3JCaGu

Comment: You drag the collection view using interface builder, but to access it from code you need to create an IBOutlet property in your code that attaches to the collection view in the nib. Without that, the system has no idea that the collection view in the nib is the same collection view that you're referencing in your code.

Comment: thanks guys. i finally figured out my problem by making a new IBOutlet connection for collection view and self the collectionview delegate and collectionview datasource.